# Janrain mobile integration using RESTFul API? for Windows, iOS and Andorid

Tags: android, ios, client-server, janrain

Sorry, i  know its not programming or code related question.

Anyone here integrate Janrain in their mobile solution. Janrain has mobile app SDK for iOS and Android but we don't want to include external SDK/Library.

Can we achieve all functionality/features using Janrain RESTFul API? e.g. Login, Social Login, Registration..
Or it is mandatory to have janrain SDK in mobile app?

Please share janrain integration detail in you have in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory to have the Janrain SDK in your mobile app.  The Janrain Mobile SDK is really just a library of code that interacts with the Janrain OAUTH RESTful API endpoints.

http://developers.janrain.com/rest-api/methods/authentication/oauth/auth_native/

The Mobile SDK does make handling the Social Identity Provider interactions a little simpler but in general these are all using Social Login endpoints as well.  Not all of the Social Login endpoints are fully documented for "build-your-own" development.  However, if you look at the Mobile SDK source code and spend some time understanding the sample application that comes with the Mobile SDK then it should be pretty easy to reverse engineer what endpoints are being used.

If you are working for a Janrain Enterprise customer then you should contact your account manager to see if you can get some official assistance and perhaps additional information that isn't found on the web site.